# Using aliased email address to send mail from Google App Engine

Tags: google-app-engine, email

I own a domain, call it `myDomain.com`, which currently masks a Google App Engine project. I have multiple alias email addresses associated with this domain, e.g. `rsvp@myDomain.com`, that are all set up to forward to my Gmail account. I am unable to ever authorize these aliased email accounts as Editors of my Google App via the Developer's Console because Google always sees the aliased email as my Gmail account and says...

> You are already a member of this project, you cannot accept this
>   invitation.

...whenever I attempt to accept the invite to Edit.

Thus when I attempt to send an email via an aliased email from my deployed app, I get an `InvalidSenderError: Unauthorized sender` error.

Is it possible to use my domain's aliased emails to send emails from my app if they are forwarding to the same account that deployed the app? I will try an experiment this evening where I use a different forwarding email account, but this is not sustainable, as I would like to have many (>10) aliased email addresses.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately, you can't send from email aliases using the built in mail service in GAE. It must be a a full user with developer access to that project.

We switched over to using The SendGrid integration for much the same reason.

There is a built in library for it in GAE and you and get a free SG account for low volume. Check out docs at https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/python/mail/sendgrid for more info.